# Get simple search form to work across multiple models without Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search

I have seen a few posts here about searching across multiple models ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044415/rails-search-across-multiple-models) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025058/search-for-multiple-words-across-multiple-models), in particular). However, I'm wondering if I can adapt Ryan's Railscast #37 to do this for three or four models without having to figure out Thinking Sphinx as I'm a beginner to all this.

As I said I have a few models, although I only reference two for brevity below, and I made a `searches_controller` with `index` and `show` actions.

On the models I included Ryan's model code:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

And in the `searches_controller` I have the following:

```
def index
  @profiles = Profile.search(params[:search])
  @employers = Employer.search(params[:search])
end

def show
  @profiles = Profile.search(params[:search])
  @employers = Employer.search(params[:search])
end
```

In my `searches/show.html.erb` I have the following:

```
  <%= @profiles.each do |profile| %>
  <div class="question">
    <div class="questionHeader">
      <h5 class="questionTitle"><%= link_to profile.first_name, profile %></h5>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end question -->
  <% end %>
  <%= @employers.each do |employer| %>
  <div class="question">
    <div class="questionHeader">
      <h5 class="questionTitle"><%= link_to employer.name, employer %></h5>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end question -->
  <% end %>
```

When I perform the search, my show renders what looks like three empty arrays `[][][]`.

Without ditching this and moving to Thinking Sphinx is there anything I can do to get this working using the simple form below?

```
<% form_tag searches_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "#", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @tvalent2 how did you go about this or it ended on the wind

Comment: @theAreba I think I went with Ransack instead for the time being - https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack