# Get a model relationship with texticle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, texticle

I'm searching for cars in my database, and using texticle.

I have manufacturers, styles, engines tables. A car is made up of the relationships between these tables. Every car has a manufacturer, a style and an engine.

what I'm trying to figure out is how to return a complete result when the user searches terms in texticle.

I saw the system-wide search in the texticle documentation, but that is only showing me that it will return results from all the tables. How do I get that into a consistent format?

What I'm looking for is that when a user searches for Ford, I'll give them all the `ford` results for each style and engine type. When a user searches `ford coupe`, they'll get a list of all the ford coupes.

But here's the big one (I think), I want to return the results from the car table.

Do I have to take each result from texticle and then search my cars table for the relationships? Or is there a betterway?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/2044631/1251349 , maybe this is more of what your looking for

Comment: thanks @AndrewWei, I find sphinx and solr to be quite heavy-weight, and what I like about texticle is how easy it is to implement. I'm just building a proof of concept now, so want something fairly quick and dirty.